# Will reports still be accessible once an App is removed from Sale from the Apple Store

Tags: ios, app-store, report, reporting, disable

I am planning to remove from sale an App from App Store Connect, I would like to know Will reports still be accessible once an App is removed from Sale?

Thank you in advance.

I want to be sure I can still pull the reports once the App has been removed from Sale.